# Send newsletter by cron jobs with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have searching about 2 hs about this theme of cron jobs and codeigniter, my problem is to set the command by cpanel to send newsletter every day I cant access to the controller and its function.

THe mail that I receive copy all the code of my index page..

I think I have to make some route at the index look the command line that I use:

```
php -q /home/xxx/public_html/index.php report send
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try php -q /home/xxx/public_html/index.php/report/send

Comment: Say: No input file specified.

Comment: you sure about the php part? is it not /usr/bin/php or some other absolute path?

Comment: What you have looks correct to me (though I've never used the `-q` option). What happens when you access the same method through the browser (whatever.com/reports/send)? If it works there, I'd suspect permissions issues. If not, there's probably an error in report.php.

Comment: I can access it normal, it's send me the email to my account.

The strange is that it send me the index code of my page..

Comment: did you write no direct access allowed in the start of your controller......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .......If you want a particular program to run, say, once every day at 10.45 am, the time portion of the cron schedule should read like this

```
45 10 * * * wget http://server_path/application/controller/method
```

Comment: Thats work perfectly but if I want to save a log of the mailings, i'm mean the script return me like xxx@email.com SEND OK or its fail FAILED. In the email of cron that i receive like admin dont show me that..
its say:

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `envio.13'

     0K                                                         481 =0.1s

2013-02-19 08:50:01 (481 B/s) - `envio.13' saved [53]

Comment: if you want to save log do one thing after you sent mail save that time stamp and to whom you sent mail in a database table that will be useful for you in future also